# Cannot connect docker container on ECS Fargate to RDS db instance

Tags: docker, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs

I've been pulling my hair out trying to connect my docker container on ECS Fargate to my RDS instance without success for the past 3 hours and I don't know why it's not working.

I have a ruby docker image with db config like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
production:
  <<: *default
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: my_project_db
```

where

```
DATABASE_URL=myprojectdbinstance.c42n4hggvli1.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

which is the RDS endpoint URL.
My database identifier name is `myprojectdbinstance` and initial database name is `my_project_db`.

When I run my ECS task I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: We could not find your database: myprojectdbinstance.c42n4hggvli1.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com. Which can be found in the database configuration file located at config/database.yml

PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "myprojectdbinstance.c42n4hggvli1.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: Name does not resolve
```

My ECS and RDS db are in the same VPC. The ECS Task is in `projects-alb-sg` security group, my RDS accepts inbound traffic from `projects-alb-sg` security group. My VPC supports DNS resolution and DNS hostnames and RDS database is publicly available. I have created DB subnet group with the same subnets where my ECS task is located. I have already tried all possible settings and it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
My VPC has DNS resolution enabled
[image]

I span up an EC2 instance and did `nslookup` and here's the output

```
nslookup myprojectdbinstance.c42n4hggvli1.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com
Server:         10.0.0.2
Address:        10.0.0.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
myprojectdbinstance.c42n4hggvli1.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com   canonical name = ec2-18-193-32-4.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
Name:   ec2-18-193-32-4.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Address: 10.0.1.233
```

DB security group (it allows access from `sg-047f1acd163d6f380`)
[image]

`sg-047f1acd163d6f380` security group that I set to my ECS task

[image]

Comment: To debug this I would start by spinning up a tiny EC2 instance in the same subnet the ECS is being deployed to, and try to do a `nslookup` or `ping` of `myprojectdbinstance.c42n4hggvli1.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com` on that EC2 instance. For your issue I would suspect the VPC setting `enableDnsSupport` being disabled, but you are sure that is enabled? Are you sure you are viewing the correct VPC when you look at those settings?

Comment: 100% I am setting the correct VPC. I've added a screen shot of my VPC settings.

Comment: At this point I'm wondering if the error Ruby is giving you is really the correct error message. I wonder if it's really getting a network timeout or something. Can you post what your security group settings for the RDS server are? You could try assigning the same security group to the EC2 server that you are assigning to the ECS task, and then see if you can connect to the RDS server from the EC2 server.

Comment: I added my security groups settings.

Comment: If that's the only inbound rule for the database, then why did you make the database publicly accessible? Making the database publicly accessible can mess up security group rules like this, because the network requests may end up getting routed to the public address of the database server, which results in the security group ID associations being dropped.

Comment: So what do you suggest I do? Move the DB to a private subnet and disable public access setting on the DB?

Comment: I would suggest simply disabling public access on the DB. The subnet isn't very relevant if you have that disabled. But before doing that, I would suggest simply opening the security group on the DB to all traffic, to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I did what you suggested but it still didn't work. I opened permissions to the db and was able to connect to it from EC2. The error says the database was not found so I thought I'd try overwriting the ENV to `DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres@myendpoint/my_project_db` and it worked. Interesting because all the sources I found in the internet mention only the endpoint. Lesson learned :) Thank you so much for your time and for your help :)